# how to paint on live camera using Camera overlay view : issues in code

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am trying to make application to draw on live camera. In that I have created a class with xib called **`PaintView`**, in which all the paint related functionality is running.

I am adding the `paintview` to `cameraoverlay` view. The view is added properly. But when I am touching the screen of device, the application is not able to draw anything, and the log shows following error

> < Error >: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x11b540
>
> < Error >: CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor: invalid context 0x11b540

my code for adding sub view is

```
// Insert the overlay
       
overlay = [[PaintView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PaintView" bundle:nil];

//overlay.pickerReference = self.imagePicker;

[self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView addSubview:overlay.view];

[self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView bringSubviewToFront:overlay.view];

[self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

//self.imagePicker.delegate = overlay;
        
[self presentModalViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Please help me, how to draw on live camera  !!!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: In Paint view I am creating Image view, which is initialized like

drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

drawImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 320, 440);

[self.view addSubview:drawImage];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:drawImage];

Comment: Are you doing your drawing in the drawRect: method of PaintView?

Comment: Yes , I am drawing the drawRect: method, below is the code

Comment: drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];

 drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;

 [self.view addSubview:drawImage];

[drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, drawImage.frame.size.width, drawImage.frame.size.height)];

Comment: You are calling drawInRect on drawImage.image, but you set that image to nil in your initWithImage method.

Comment: I changed it , but still same issue , the context is invalid is the response in log file.

Comment: You changed what?  Please edit your question to show the code where you do the drawing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have got the solution ,

I was making mistake, as the Context is not necessary to use, it will create issues.

We need to use UIBezierPath, and the issues are solved. I am able to draw on live camera.

[here the reference to the link](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/05/uibezierpath-tutorial-for-iphone-sdk-40.html).

Yea.....